# MySQL 5.6 Slave has no Binlog generated

Tags: mysql

In my MySQL 5.6 environment, I have A -> B -> C replication setup. On C slave, there is no mysql binlog generated since I set it up as a slave. But the replication is running per `show slave status`. The Slave_SQL_Running_State showed "Slave has read all relay log; waiting for the slave I/O thread to update it". The `show master status` on C slave showed it is on "mysql-bin.000003" position 120. That file was dated on Nov 29, not today. I have checked C slave my.cnf and I have binlog configured:

```
log-bin=/mysql-binlog/mysql-bin
binlog_format=mixed
max_binlog_size = 200M
```

There is relay-bin log on C slave generated and kept current.

What is the reason C slave has no binlog?

Comment: I would assume because `log_slave_updates` is disabled on C. So it has relay logs, but changes in the relay log are not themselves logged. If you execute an original change on C that is not from replication, that should be logged in its binlog.

Comment: Please ask database admin related questions on the dedicated DBA sister site of SO, as SO is a programming focused site!